# Simple way to define nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have some nested python dictionaries.  I want to use the dictionary to organize various totals that my script tallies.  I defined the dictionary as:

```
periodDict = {'Group01':{'Bin01':{'Tally01':0, 'Tally02':0}, \
                         'Bin02':{'Tally01':0, 'Tally02':0}}, \
              'Group02':{'Bin01':{'Tally01':0, 'Tally02':0}, \
                         'Bin02':{'Tally01':0, 'Tally02':0}}}
```

My problem is that in the real script, I have 52 periods, 25 groups and 12 bins.

Is there a simpler way to define and initialize the dictionary that to build a ***very large*** dictionary within the script?  And, making changes to the dictionary structure is a nightmare.  Naturally, I’d like to do something like:

```
binDict = {'Tally01':0, 'Tally02':0}
groupDict = {'Bin01':binDict, 'Bin02':binDict}
periodDict = {'Group01':groupDict, 'Group02':groupDict}
```

but that doesn't work because any change to a Group01 tally will also change the corresponding Group02 tally.  For example:

```
In [1]: binDict = {'Tally01':0, 'Tally02':0} #Initalize to 0

In [2]: groupDict = {'Bin01':binDict, 'Bin02':binDict}

In [3]: periodDict = {'Group01':groupDict, 'Group02':groupDict}

In [4]: periodDict['Group01']['Bin01']['Tally01'] = 1 # Change one value

In [5]: periodDict['Group01']['Bin01']['Tally01']
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: periodDict['Group02']['Bin01']['Tally01'] # Group 2 also changed
Out[6]: 1
```

What can I do to make this problem simpler and easier to manage?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you hardcoding the data for the  52 periods, 25 groups and 12 bins into your code (as opposed to getting from some other data-source)? The problem would be easier to solve if the nested-dictionaries was created programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using references to the dictionaries, use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to create deep copies of them. This way updating one of won't affect the others:

```
from copy import deepcopy

binDict = {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}
groupDict = {'Bin01': deepcopy(binDict), 'Bin02': deepcopy(binDict)}
periodDict = {'Group01': deepcopy(groupDict), 'Group02': deepcopy(groupDict)}
```

Comment: Very simple solution and works exactly as I need it to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use loops so you can create it programmatically, don't create it "by hand":

```
>>> num_groups = range(1, 26)
>>> num_bins = range(1, 13)
>>> num_tally = range(1, 3)
>>> period_dict = {}
>>> for gn in num_groups:
...     groupdict = {}
...     period_dict[f"Group{gn:02}"] = groupdict
...     for bn in num_bins:
...         bindict = {}
...         groupdict[f"Bin{bn:02d}"] = bindict
...         for tn in num_tally:
...             bindict[f"Tally{tn:02d}"] = 0
...
```

And the result:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(period_dict)
{'Group01': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group02': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group03': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group04': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group05': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group06': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group07': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group08': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group09': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group10': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group11': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group12': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group13': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group14': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group15': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group16': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group17': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group18': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group19': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group20': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group21': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group22': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group23': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group24': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}},
 'Group25': {'Bin01': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin02': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin03': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin04': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin05': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin06': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin07': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin08': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin09': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin10': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin11': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0},
             'Bin12': {'Tally01': 0, 'Tally02': 0}}}
```

This way, you aren't sharing `dict`s:

```
>>> period_dict['Group03']['Bin04']['Tally01'] = 99
>>> period_dict['Group06']['Bin04']['Tally01']
0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to initialize the whole dictionary from the beginning you could do this like this:

```
periodDict = {}
groupnames = ['Group{:02d}'.format(nr+1) for nr in range(52)]
binnames = ['Bin{:02d}'.format(nr+1) for nr in range(25)]
tallynames = ['Tally{:02d}'.format(nr+1) for nr in range(12)]

for groupname in groupnames:
    periodDict[groupname] = {}
    for binname in binnames:
        periodDict[groupname][binname] = {}
        for tallyname in tallynames:
            periodDict[groupname][binname][tallyname] = 0
```